Magento View Only Permission for Products
We Want to create new user for backend in which that user should have only option to view product information. So I tried below steps  :
system > permissions > users & roles :


Issue :
New User can able to edit information also, but i want user can able to view only

You should try this extension, It provide many access level features
https://amasty.com/advanced-permissions-for-magento-2.html
the module enables you to limit the access to:
Specific products;
Categories;
Store views;
Websites;
Product attributes;
CMS elements;
Dashboard statistics;
Reports.

Thanks for the extension, by default magento dont support the feature ?

Not, unfortunately :(
